# Join 2 CSV and replace row values in PHP

Tags: php, string, join, csv, replace

I have 2 csv:

the first one look like this:

city , text
Seattle , **[city]** is a **[property]** in the middle of **[county]** and have **[citizens]** citizens

the second one look like this:

city , property , county , citizens
Seattle , City , King County , 608.660

I will that the output look like so:

City , Text
Seattle , **Seattle** is a **City** in the middle of **King County** and have **608.660** citizens.

The Logic is so, combine two csv, read them, if the City name is the same, replace all the strings [value name] present in the first csv under the column "Text" with the value with the same value name present in the csv2.

After replacing the values, the output will be print in a new csv (csv3).

Thanks in advance,

Ivan

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started:

```
//Create an array of city->template
$handle = fopen("templates.csv", "r");
if($handle === false){
    die("Failed to open templates");
}
$templatesArr = array();
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) {
    $templatesArr[$data[0]] = $data[1];//Probably don't want to hard code these here
}
fclose($handle);


//Loop through the data populating the templates.
$handle = fopen("data.csv", "r");
if($handle === false){
    die("Failed to open template data");
}
$outArr = array();
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) {
    $city = $data[0];
    $template = $templatesArr[$city];
    //Replace template data with csv data.
    $template = str_replace(array('city','property','county','citizens'),array($city,$data[1],$data[2],$data[3]),$template);
    $outArr[$city] = $template;
}
fclose($handle);
```

Please note this isn't tested and doesn't do any sanity checking, you'll probably want to tidy it up a bit first.

Comment: Hi Jim! Thank You very much! Your code helped me a lot! It makes exactly what i want, now i wanna write the output into a new csv. I tried this code:  
`$list = array (array("City","Text"),array($city,$template));  
$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');  
foreach ($list as $fields) {  
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);  
}  
fclose($fp);`  

I putted this code into the second while (the populating data loop), unfortunately writes only the last one line. I have more lines with different cities and text, but dunno why it writes only the last one. do you know why?

thanks a lot!

Ivan